# How to upload only files without creating SD-Card path in AWS S3?

Tags: android, amazon-web-services, path, sd-card

I am uploading an image from SD-Card to AWS S3, it's uploading correctly but the issue is it's creating SD-card path folder in AWS like this "/storage/sdcard0/Documents/ABCD/xyz.jpg", i want only to files without creating any folders.

```
String csvPath = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath()+"/Documents/ABCD/xyz.jpg";

S3PutObjectTask s3 = new S3PutObjectTask(this,fileName);
s3.execute(fileName);

public class S3PutObjectTask extends AsyncTask<String, Void, S3TaskResult> {

    /*Variable*/
    Activity activity;
    String imageName;
    String fileName;
    ProgressDialog pDialog;

    /*AWS*/
    AmazonS3Client s3Client;

    public S3PutObjectTask(Activity activity,String fileName) {
        this.activity = activity;
        this.fileName = fileName;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute(){
        super.onPreExecute();

        pDialog = new ProgressDialog(activity);
        pDialog.setTitle("");
        pDialog.setMessage("Please Wait...");
        pDialog.setCancelable(false);
        pDialog.show();

        s3Client = new AmazonS3Client(new BasicAWSCredentials(AppConstants.ACCESS_KEY_ID, AppConstants.SECRET_KEY));
        s3Client.setRegion(Region.getRegion(Regions.US_EAST_1));
    }

    @Override
    protected S3TaskResult doInBackground(String... uris) {

        S3TaskResult result = new S3TaskResult();

        if (uris == null || uris[0].length()==0){
            return null;
        }

        Uri selectedCSV = Uri.fromFile(new File(uris[0]));

        ContentResolver resolver = activity.getContentResolver();

        File file=new File(uris[0]);

        ObjectMetadata metadata = new ObjectMetadata();
        metadata.setContentType("image/jpeg");

        if(file.length()!=0){
            metadata.setContentLength(file.length());
        }

        try {
            PutObjectRequest por = new PutObjectRequest(AppConstants.getAbcdListBucket(),uris[0],
            resolver.openInputStream(selectedCSV),metadata);
            s3Client.putObject(por);


        } catch (Exception exception) {
            result.setErrorMessage(exception.getMessage());
        }
        return result;
    }

    protected void onPostExecute(S3TaskResult result){
        if(pDialog!=null && pDialog.isShowing()){
            pDialog.dismiss();
    }
}
```

Please kindly go through my code and suggest me some solution.

Answer (score 2):

The 2nd parameter "String key" controls what folder you are uploading to and what the file name is.

```
PutObjectRequest(AppConstants.getAbcdListBucket(), "My Folder/filename.jpg", resolver.openInputStream(selectedCSV),metadata);
```

Comment: hey thanks can you tell me how to upload only files without creating any path in AWS...